# Magento2: How to set minumum order price for specyfic group

Tags: magento2, orders, price, group

I see Magento provide possible set minimum order qty. For specific group. But how to set **minimum order price** for specific group?

I see is available option only set for all groups minimum order price in store.

But how to set example:

- Group I: wholesale: min order price 200$
- Group II: Dropshipping partners: no minimum order price

Comment: Magento 2 doesn't provide functionality where admin can  set up the minimum order value for each group of customers, But you can find the extensions online.

Comment: Yes I see but is available only paid extension. Maybe you know any free extension?